# Can't query 'job_queue_processes in Oracle DB 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to query the value of job_queue_processes:

```
select value from v$parameter where name='job_queue_processes';
```

But I can't, I get a

```
`ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`
```

Querying user jobs is fine, as well:

```
select * from user_jobs
```

Querying version is fine, as well:

```
select * from v$version where rownum<2;
```

SYS.dba_jobs_running & SYS.dba_jobs are not working either (ORA-00942: table or view does not exist)

```
select * from SYS.dba_jobs_running;
select * from SYS.dba_jobs;
```

Comment: As which use did you query the v$ view?

Comment: I don't understand the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SYS@research 15-APR-15> grant select on v_$parameter to sample;

Grant succeeded.

SAMPLE@research 15-APR-15> select value from v$parameter where   name='job_queue_processes';

VALUE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1000
```

Comment: Show parameters query failed

Comment: looks like you dont have permissions on that table to view the details, 
please run this query , updated in answer

Comment: sample is the username, please replace that with the user you are trying to run the query from

Comment: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist, so I guess I don't have permissions

Comment: Yep, if you are not able to grant the permissions please ask your DBA to help you with it

Comment: @Nuñito de la Calzada: this was exactly what I was looking for with my question above (but there was a small type; it was meant to be _"As which use**r** did you query ..."_) because `v_$parameter` can't be queried by normal users. Either you have to ask your DBA to grant you access, or you are a DBA and grant `select` to this view yourself as user _SYS_ :D